# PHP using sqlite3 with forms

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am new to php and sqlite and wanted to make a form that inserts everything there into the database.

This is my contact.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>G6 Mall | Contact</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Terminal_Dosis_300.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">.bg {behavior:url("js/PIE.htc")}</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page6">
<div class="body1">
  <div class="body2">
    <div class="body3">
      <div class="main">
        <!-- header -->
        <header>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="index.php" id="logo"></a></h1>
            <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
              <div>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="">
                <input class="input" type="text" value="Site Search" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Site Search'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Site Search' ) this.value=''">
              </div>
            </form>
            <nav>
              <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="directory1.html">Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                <li id="active" class="end"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
        <!-- / header-->
        <!-- content -->
        <section id="content">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>General Enquiry Form</h2>
            <form id="FeedbackForm" action="post.php" method="post">
              <div>
                <div class="wrapper"> <span>Name:</span>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="NAME">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper"> <span>Contact:</span>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="CONTACT">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper"> <span>E-mail:</span>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="EMAIL">
                </div>
                <div class="textarea_box"> <span>Message: (50char)</span>
                  <textarea name="COMMENT" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
                <!--<span>&nbsp;</span> <a href="#" class="button">Clear</a> <a href="#" class="button">Send</a> </div>-->
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body4">
  <div class="main">
    <section id="content2">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h2>Where are we located at? </h2>
            <strong>Lot-6 G6 Street, Wollongong, 6666 NSW</strong>
            <p><!--spacing between the headers-->
         </div>
          <div class="line3 wrapper">
         <article class="col2">
            <h2>G6 Card privileges+ </h2>
            <div class="pad"> <span class="col3"> <strong>
              Telephone:<br>
              Email: </strong> </span>
              +614 1234 6666<br>
              <a href="#">g6card@g6.com</a> </div>
          </article>
         <article class="col2">
            <h2>Customer Service Centre </h2>
            <div class="pad"> <span class="col3"> <strong>
              Telephone:<br>
              Email: </strong> </span>
              +614 1234 5555<br>
              <a href="#">custserv@g6.com</a> </div>
          </article>
          <article class="col2">
            <h2>Advertisement & Promotion</h2>
            <div class="pad"> <span class="col3"> <strong>
              Telephone:<br>
              Fax No:<br>
              Email: </strong> </span>
              +614 1234 7777<br>
              +614 1234 1212<br>
              <a href="#">adsPromo@g6.com</a> </div>
          </article>

          <article class="col2">
            <h2>Leasing</h2>
            <div class="pad"> <span class="col3"> <strong>
              Telephone:<br>
              Fax No:<br>
              Email: </strong> </span>
              +614 7728 8878<br>
              +614 7726 8869<br>
              <a href="#">leasing@g6.com</a> </div>
          </article></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / content -->
<div class="main">
  <!-- footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper"> <span class="left"> Copyright &copy; <a href="#">G6</a>. All Rights Reserved<br>
      Design by LM-02</a><br>
      </span>
      <ul id="icons">
      Connect with us: <br>
        <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Facebook"><img src="images/icon1.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="normaltip" title="Twitter"><img src="images/icon4.png" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
  </footer>
  <!-- / footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i made a post.php and put this code down

```
<?php

$NAME = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['NAME']);
$CONTACT = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['CONTACT']);
$EMAIL = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['EMAIL']);
$COMMENT = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['COMMENT']);

   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('final_mall_management_system.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

   $sql =<<<EOF
      INSERT INTO Enquiry (Name,Contact,Email,Comment)
      VALUES ( '$NAME', '$CONTACT', '$EMAIL', '$COMMENT' );
EOF;

   $ret = $db->exec($sql);
   if(!$ret){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Records created successfully\n";
   }
   $db->close();
?>
```

When I entered the data in the form and click the submit it doesn't work I get this instead

```
open('final_mall_management_system.db'); } } $db = new MyDB(); if(!$db){ echo $db->lastErrorMsg(); } else { echo "Opened database successfully\n"; } $sql =<<exec($sql); if(!$ret){ echo $db->lastErrorMsg(); } else { echo "Records created successfully\n"; } $db->close(); ?>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone please help me?

```
<section id="content">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>General Enquiry Form</h2>
            <form id="FeedbackForm" action="post.php" method="post">
              <div>
                <div class="wrapper"> <span>Name:</span>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="NAME">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper"> <span>Contact:</span>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="CONTACT">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper"> <span>E-mail:</span>
                  <input type="text" class="input" name="EMAIL">
                </div>
                <div class="textarea_box"> <span>Message: (50char)</span>
                  <textarea name="COMMENT" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
                <!--<span>&nbsp;</span> <a href="#" class="button">Clear</a> <a href="#" class="button">Send</a> </div>-->
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Is the main section of the "form" html code from the whole code (content.html) that i showed above.

Comment: Make sure PHP is actually running on your web server. Run `<?php phpinfo();` in a file called `info.php`, from your browser, and check it works.

Comment: ohmygod thats it. I feel so silly, thank you so much

Comment: No worries. I'll vote to put on hold, as the question probably won't be of widespread future use, but it was well formatted and clear, and your problem is solved. +1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the solution (PHP not running in the web server) is not likely to be of widespread use to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Change remove  EOF thing and use double quotes for your sql, I think that's the problem.

```
 $sql ="INSERT INTO Enquiry (Name,Contact,Email,Comment)
  VALUES ( '$NAME', '$CONTACT', '$EMAIL', '$COMMENT' )";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did what you said but the error is still though it had changed a little  


open('final_mall_management_system.db'); } } $db = new MyDB(); if(!$db){ echo $db->lastErrorMsg(); } else { echo "Opened database successfully\n"; } $sql ="INSERT INTO Enquiry (Name,Contact,Email,Comment) VALUES ( '$NAME', '$CONTACT', '$EMAIL', '$COMMENT' )"; $ret = $db->exec($sql); if(!$ret){ echo $db->lastErrorMsg(); } else { echo "Records created successfully\n"; } $db->close(); ?>

Comment: You must have something else in the code that exposes the php. Is the extension correct? It's weird that it starts displaying code right after "->"

Answer (score 0):

most likely you redefined constructor to SQLite3 class itself.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
try changing

```
function __construct() {
    $this->open('final_mall_management_system.db');
}
```

to

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->open('final_mall_management_system.db');
}
```